# ASP.NET 4 / IIS HTTP Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to setup an ASP.NET site locally, When I run the debugger I get no errors in the code, but when I goto the site I see the following:

`HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error`
`The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`
`Module IIS Web Core
Notification    Unknown
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070032
Config Error    The configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
Config File \\?\C:\SecondCity\Website\web.config
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/
Physical Path

Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined`

How do I fix this, I believe this is an IIS issue, but everything I have researched is not clear to me how to fix this.

Comment: does iis have read permissions on your web.config

Comment: This could be caused by a few things, most likely a missing section declaration... Can you post your web.config file?

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that you have the [correct framework version](http://forums.asp.net/t/1547286.aspx) set in your application pool?   System.web.extensions will not be recognized in anything lower than .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to configuration sections in web.config. You need add section group like below in the

```
                 <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>

                         <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">

                            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>

                         <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>

                            <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>

                            <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
```

Please read the articles related to this from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/10/handling-error-while-upgrading-asp-net-webrole-from-net-3-5-to-net-4-0-the-configuration-section-system-web-extensions-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-missing-a-section-declaration.aspx?Redirected=true)